# Can't Store pig relation into Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, apache-pig

Hi I am trying to store pig relation into HBase.

```
store result INTO 'hbase://hourlyAggregation' using org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('countDetails:ansCount countDetails:divCount countDetails:unansCount countDetails:engCount');
```

This is running fine in local. when I tried to run pig in mapred mode my job is failing and my log is showing no error

```
 ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message
Details at logfile: /home/HadoopUser/pig_1384412383791.log

Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:119)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:172)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:144)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:90)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:500)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:107)
================================================================================
```

my profile is as follows

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/hadoop/jdk1.6.0_39
export HADOOP_HOME=$MY_HOME/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u4
export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:.
export HIVE_HOME=$MY_HOME/hive-0.7.1-cdh3u4
export PIG_HOME=$MY_HOME/pig-0.8.1-cdh3u4
export HBASE_HOME=$MY_HOME/hbase-0.90.6-cdh3u4
export PIG_CLASSPATH=”`${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase classpath`:$PIG_CLASSPATH”
```

please help me on this

I even tried to register jars of zookeeper and hbase in pig_home/lib

JT log

```
14-Nov-2013 14:48:29 (17sec)


java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage' with arguments '[countDetails:ansCount countDetails:divCount countDetails:unansCount countDetails:engCount]'
    at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:502)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.relationalOperators.POStore.getStoreFunc(POStore.java:218)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputCommitter.getCommitters(PigOutputCommitter.java:85)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputCommitter.<init>(PigOutputCommitter.java:68)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputFormat.getOutputCommitter(PigOutputFormat.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.initialize(Task.java:511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
```

Comment: Could you post the correspondig Hadoop task's log as well? Did you make sure that Pig and HBase are correctly up and running?

Comment: when I run the script in local mode I can see values in my HBase table

Answer (score 0):

registering hbase,zookeeper jar in PIG/lib and guava jar in hbase lib did worked thanks Lorand Bendig for ur support.

Comment: could you add details of how you registered that? Did you copy the JARs to that location? Which JARs ?

Comment: If tried to register some libraries, but still have the same problem: REGISTER /XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.0.3.jar
REGISTER /XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-client-1.0.3.jar
REGISTER /XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.0.3.jar
REGISTER /XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-1.0.3.jar
REGISTER /XXX/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar
REGISTER /XXX/hbase/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar
REGISTER /XXX/hbase/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar
REGISTER /XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-1.0.3.jar
REGISTER /XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-annotations-1.0.3.jar
REGISTER /XXX/hbase/lib/hbase-thrift-1.0.3.jar